Who is responsible for damage caused by a planned power outage?
I am soon to have a planned power outage that I was notified of and have taken the recommended steps by the national grid (UK) to prepare for this.
A similar question was asked here about the liability in case of a power surge damaging electrical equipment.
Does this change in the case of a planned power outage whereby prior notice was sent to those it will affect?

Are you thinking of any entity in particular? E.g. the supplier?

I think if the outage could cause you a significant loss (e.g. broken machinery) you should be prepared for it.

@Lag In this case it would likely be the entity giving notice and actioning the outage (National Grid)

Basically, the question comes down to whether the notice of the outage also serves as notice that there may be a surge when power comes back on, and whether that transfers responsibility for preparing for this to the customer. Is that right?

Is a recommended stop to pull the main breaker on the panel and not re-engage until after the mains are live again? If you are worried about damage, you can take additional steps to protect your sensitive equipment.

When there is a severe electrical storm approaching, I might switch off the computer equipment, and disconnect all power and data cables from external sockets. You have to take some responsibility for owning sensitive equipment. More generally you can also safeguard the equipment with a surge protector.

Are you asking about physical damage to equipment, or other "damage" such as financial, emotional, etc.?  Because several comments presume equipment damage, but that would make this a dupe of the other question and this one should be closed...

In a civil lawsuit for money damages, on either a breach of contract theory, or a breach of another legal duty theory (i.e. a tort action), you have a duty to try to mitigate your damages. If you have advanced notice of a planned power outage, it is very unlikely that you can make a case that you didn't have an opportunity to fully mitigate your damages.

What about damages that can't be mitigated?  For example, an aluminum smelter needs to be taken offline well before the outage to permit a clean shutdown, and takes quite some time to warm back up again afterwards.  Sure, you can mitigate damage to the equipment, but you're still losing a day or two of production.

@Mark Did the power company guarantee them uninterrupted power? If not, there is no promise breached.

@Mark If you really have an aluminum smelter, the power company will know, as you're probably their best customer. Im assuming that in such a case, they will announce the outage well in advance and even discuss the options with you (e.g. plan the outage during a planed service window)

As an aluminium smelter, you will likely have significant power supply capability yourself. Like a 20kW ship diesel engine. Make sure your Diesel tanks are full. Some companies did test runs which all worked fine, but nobody filled up the diesel tanks :-(
